# How to increase the Kafka consumers in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am creating a Spring Boot application with Kafka support.
I have created a Producer and a Consumer and everything is working like a charm. In runtime I have one consumer. I wanted to have many consumers, the same number of partitions of my topic.

How to create many consumers?

I have been searching in documentation but with no success.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and set the concurrency parameter. It creates 1 or more `KafkaMessageListenerContainers` based on concurrency. If the `ContainerProperties` is configured with TopicPartitions, the TopicPartitions are distributed evenly across the instances.

For example

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setConcurrency(12);
```

Comment: If you are using `@KafkaListener`, it has had a `concurrency` property (since 2.2) which overrides the container factory's default setting.

Comment: In this case, the clientId is generated dynamically for each listener ?

Comment: Is there a max number of concurrency level that can be set? Let's say if I have 1 core and 1 GB of ram for my consumer in an container, then what is the optimal number of threads can be spawned?